# Rename 'moto-x' to 'motorola-moto-x'?

Tags: discussion, tags

Generally, our device-specific tags follow the pattern `<manufacturer>-<device>`, which is the case for all Motorola devices as well – with the exception of the Moto-X.

Shouldn't we …

1. Rename [moto-x](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moto-x) to `motorola-moto-x` to match that pattern
2. optionally, have a `moto-x` synonym pointing to the renamed tag?

PS: Same for [moto-e](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moto-e) and [motorola-moto-e](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola-moto-e) plus [samsung-galaxy-note-3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-note-3) and [samsung-note-3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-note-3) it seems.

Comment: I would agree but "Moto X" is a family now: 1st Gen, and now the 2nd Gen. So [motorola-moto-x] would  really be device specific to 1st Gen, leaving the younger 2nd Gen down the path.

Comment: Not sure whether they all need separate tags (we have other examples with "one tag for a family", see e.g. the `nexus*` tags). But of course, an option would be, while being on it, to create a "group" of tags using the pattern `motorola-moto-x-?gen` or `motorola-moto-x-????` (so either by "gen" or by "year")

Comment: I thought we did have `-x#` tags. I'll have to look when I'm not on mobile.

Comment: @MatthewRead We definitely have not, I've checked that (and just now re-checked). Typing `moto-x` in the search box on the tags page gives only one result: `moto-x` itself.

Comment: I'm indifferent as to how we handle the 1st/2nd generation thing, but `motorola-moto-x` would at least be consistent with our other tags, even if we intended it to cover the whole "family".

Comment: @eldarerathis I've just added the moto-e to this list, same thing (Firelord just pointed that out on chat). Time for some action, maybe? As for your "generation issue": we don't have that currently AFAIK, so fixing the tag doesn't touch this issue – which can be dealt with separately if we see the need.